# Converting an integer to a hexadecimal string in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hex, base-conversion

Is there a built in way to convert an integer in Ruby into its hexadecimal equivalent?

Something like the opposite of [`String#to_i`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-to_i):

```
"0A".to_i(16) #=>10
```

Like perhaps:

```
"0A".hex #=>10
```

I know how to roll my own, but it's probably more efficient to use a built in Ruby function.

Answer (score 347, accepted):

You can give [`to_s`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Integer.html#method-i-to_s) a base other than 10:

```
10.to_s(16)  #=> "a"
```

Note that in ruby 2.4 `FixNum` and `BigNum` were unified in the `Integer` class. 
If you are using an older ruby check the documentation of [FixNum#`to_s`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.8/Fixnum.html#method-i-to_s) and  [BigNum#`to_s`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.8/Bignum.html#method-i-to_s)

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for but it isn't documented on the linked page
str.to_s => str
is specified as not accepting parameters and has
"Returns the receiver."
as the only documentation, but it seems to work

Comment: sorry about that copy paste mistake of course to_s on string doesn't take arguments but on Fixnum it does :)

Comment: Ah, I was looking under Integer for a .to_s method and couldn't find one.  I'll look under Fixnum next time as well

Comment: Make sure the original number is an instance of Fixnum, Float will throw an exception.

Comment: warning - if you're then splitting the hex number into byte-size segments you'll have to check the length of the result, since it won't be padded with a 0

Answer (score 90):

How about using [`%`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-25)/[`sprintf`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf):

```
i = 20
"%x" % i  #=> "14"
```

Comment: Thanks for showing this, I needed something that would get me a fixed length string prepended with '0'. ex:  "%02X" % 10 #=> "0A"

Comment: And for the other ruby newbies out there: `"#%02x%02x%02x" % [255, 0, 10] #=> "#ff000a"` - took me a bit to figure out how to send several args.

Comment: This is an extremely awesome snippet of Ruby!

Comment: I am new to Ruby, but it seems to me that there is something very subtle going on here.  Can someone explain? (+1 BTW)

Comment: @TomD % is a String method that effectively provides a shorthand for sprintf formatting (they make the same internal calls). It's documented in the String class, see http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-25

Comment: Less duplication: `[255, 0, 10].map{|x| '%02x'%x}.join`

Comment: @AaronHinni: You can also do `10.to_s(16).rjust(2, "0")`

Answer (score 83):

To summarize:

```
p 10.to_s(16) #=> "a"
p "%x" % 10 #=> "a"
p "%02X" % 10 #=> "0A"
p sprintf("%02X", 10) #=> "0A"
p "#%02X%02X%02X" % [255, 0, 10] #=> "#FF000A"
```

Answer (score 14):

Here's another approach:

```
sprintf("%02x", 10).upcase
```

see the documentation for `sprintf` here: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf

Comment: `sprintf("%02X", 10)` will be uppercase because of the upper case X. No need for the upcase method to be called.

The specific section of the kernel is this: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-format

Answer (score 6):

Just in case you have a preference for how negative numbers are formatted:

```
p "%x" % -1   #=> "..f"
p -1.to_s(16) #=> "-1"
```