# How to get gmail threadid using imap xoauth

Tags: oauth, gmail, imap

I read this [Find Gmail url-IDs via IMAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687445/find-gmail-url-ids-via-imap), but I noticed Greplin (https://www.greplin.com) is able to get thread id successfully.

Can anyone help me here?

Regards,
Manoj

Comment: Why do you think that greplin is using IMAP to get Gmail thread IDs?

Comment: I given only one oAuth access and I think to access mails we need to use gmails xoauth, may be I am wrong.

Comment: Doesn't the thread you linked say that they get the data via the atom feed?

Comment: Atom feed will give only unread messages!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gmail provides An attribute

> "X-GM-THRID"

for thread id

you can use imap fetch function for getting thread id .

see documentation here 
http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/imap/

Comment: Just FYI, I've posted an example of how to get it using PHP and Zend Mailer in http://stackoverflow.com/a/19289923/1079109. Hope it helps!

Answer (score -2):

I think that is can be access via libgmailer.php (curl) http://sourceforge.net/search/?q=libgmailer

Comment: @user691595 
I found this thread interested so I tried with  libgmailer.php 
but I am getting these error 
Fail to connect because: Gmail: Invalid request. (libgmailer: Gmail seems to have changed the URL again.)

Comment: @user691595
and one more thing . It does not use imap . See the thread "It is about using imap protocol not using curl login"

Comment: I tried to run

openssl s_client -crlf -connect imap.gmail.com:993                    
. FETCH 1:4 (X-GM-THRID)                                           
* 1 FETCH (X-GM-THRID 1327644189674155015)                         
* 2 FETCH (X-GM-THRID 1327644190303473294)                         
* 3 FETCH (X-GM-THRID 1327644189818844987)                         
* 4 FETCH (X-GM-THRID 1341989198080663261)                         
. OK Success                                                       
But in gmail web interface 1st msg uid look's like this 12f0d9019b80216a

Any ideas?

Comment: @uid 1 is  for your first email in your account. 
check with your latest message.

Comment: DONE! :) 
1327644190303473294 is decimal value. If we want to use it in URL we need to convert it to hexadecimal value. Do not trust javascript online calculator and do it on x_64 mashines.
[link](http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/apis/gmail/forum.html?place=msg%2Fgoogle-apps-gadgets-api%2FA0FpZ8LF_Ag%2FcwsXerakQFkJ)
`echo dechex(1327644190303473294); //return's 126cbd5b5f264e8e`