# "X-GM-THRID" via imap php

Tags: php, gmail, imap

Vivek, could you give an example HOWTO grab "X-GM-THRID" via imap php?

Comment: I think you clicked the wrong button somewhere: This is a public Q&A web site for programming questions.

Comment: Probably a followup question to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5220262/how-to-get-gmail-threadid-using-imap-xoauth

Comment: thanks, I tried to run  
openssl s_client -crlf -connect imap.gmail.com:993
. FETCH 1:4 (X-GM-THRID)
* 1 FETCH (X-GM-THRID 1327644189674155015)

But in gmail web interface 1st msg uid look's like this 12f0d9019b80216a

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It's simple with Zend's IMAP class. The IDs in the web interface are supposed to be HEX versions of the same number Gmail expects through IMAP (http://www.limilabs.com/blog/tag/x-gm-thrid), tough I'm still having trouble using those because if I convert them from HEX the numbers are a bit off.

```
$imap = new Zend\Mail\Protocol\Imap('imap.gmail.com', '993', true);
$imap->search(array('X-GM-THRID', '1424628081834791276');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here an example for getting the "X-GM-THRID" for a given message with `$messageId`.

```
$messageId = 1; // E.g. the message number one
$imap = new Zend_Mail_Protocol_Imap('imap.gmail.com', '993', true);
$message = $imap->requestAndResponse("FETCH $messageId (X-GM-THRID)");
$idHex = (int) $message[0][2][1];
$xGmThrid = base_convert($idHex, 10, 16);
```

Hope it helps.