# Custom IMAP command in php

Tags: php, imap

What is alternative of java imap function `doCommand` in php ?

I want to fire some custom imap extension command but I don't find any function to do that here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have switched to zend imap. 
it supports custom command and fetch.

which solved my problem.

```
<?php
require_once 'Zend/Mail/Storage/Imap.php';
require_once "Zend/Mail/Protocol/Imap.php";
require_once "Zend/Registry.php";
$protocol = new Zend_Mail_Protocol_Imap('imap.gmail.com', 993, true);
$protocol->login($user, $pass);
$protocol->select('INBOX');
$storage = new Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap($protocol);
foreach ($storage as $messageId => $message) {
  $id = $protocol->fetch('Custom Attribute', $storage->getUniqueId($messageId));
  echo "Mail from '{$message->from}': {$message->subject} : Custom Attribute $id \n";
}
?>
```

Comment: The 3rd true parameter doesn't work (anymore?). I can connect succesfully using this:  
`$protocol = new \Zend\Mail\Protocol\Imap('imap.gmail.com', 993, 'SSL');`

Answer (score 0):

Zend supports custom commends, but unfortunately does not support some basic ones like getting message parts that the default PHP imap library does... :-(

Answer (score -1):

если собираетесь искать через imap кириллические слова - у меня получилось так:

if you are going to search with IMAP non english characters - do like this:

```
$protocol->search(array("charset utf-8 X-GM-RAW", "Денис|test"));//это zend
```

т.е. в итоге запрос серверу будет такой:

a result of this request to the server will be:

```
. search charset utf-8 text Живалов|test
```

или так - используем imap расширение gmail мощный поиск:

or so - use gmail imap extension powerful search:

`. search charset utf-8 X-GM-RAW 'Живалов'|'test'`- вот так работает это апостроф на букве (Ё/тильде ~) именно в такой последовательности ни двойные кавычки, ни одинарные не работают, нуу вроде как и без всего работает:

it works, ' this apostrophe to the letter (e / ~ tilde) in that order either double quotes or single quotes do not work, sort of like without all the work:

`. search charset utf-8 X-GM-RAW Живалов|test`

I don't know how to post here some wiki, so you can reed something [here](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA_%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C_%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D1%83_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D1%83_gmail_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%83_%D1%81_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E_php_%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7_imap_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB)

Comment: why you initialize Storage_Imap with Protocol_Imap

`$storage = new Zend_Mail_Storage_Imap($protocol);`

could you explain please

Comment: can you please post you answer in English ?