# Forwarding unique URL for email in Gmail

Tags: gmail, bookmarklet, rtm

I want to forward emails from Gmail to Remember The Milk to turn them into tasks. I would like to include a link/URL pointing back to the original email so that I can easily go from Remember The Milk back to the original message. I could manually paste the unique Gmail URL from the address bar into the body of the forwarded email, but I would like to do this programmatically rather than manually. This [awesome little bookmarklet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16827485/using-gmail-message-source-generate-direct-link) creates a link to the search for the Message-Id of the original email, which is essentially good enough. But it requires clicking "More" > "Show Original" and then cutting and pasting the resultant URL. Is there a way to do this programmatically?
Thanks.