# Fetch permanent address of your email message

Tags: python, gmail, imap, poplib

I want to open particular mail(gmail) directly. gmail provide `permanent address` to each mail. for example [https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/164f55ec5fdbb840](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/164f55ec5fdbb849) here `164f55ec5fdbb840` is unique id. The link will redirecting to specific mail.

Is it possible to fetch this unique link using python. I have used IMAP, poplib modules of python and debug the same, but hard luck

Comment: Presumably you've checked out the Google GMail APIs already...?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find Gmail url-IDs via IMAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687445/find-gmail-url-ids-via-imap)