# How can I use ruby code to check for presence of a color (where color code is in hexadecimal format) on the webpage

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cucumber, watir, watir-webdriver

How to check presence a color (FFCC00) on a webpage using ruby code?

Comment: great, check out my solution below - I have updated "span" to "div" as it works exactly the same way.  As long as you can access it with the right how/what (how: index, name, id, class), you're set.

Comment: Are you looking for a Watir or Watir-Webdriver solution? You have both tags in the question. Usually it does not matter, but in the case of checking styles, they are different solutions.

Comment: @JustinKo I am looking for watir-webdriver solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Watir-Webdriver:

```
browser.element(:how => what).style("color")
```

Here's a full example:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'

@browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
@browser.goto my_site

puts @browser.div(:class => "myDiv").style("color")
```

[WATIR Google Group answer from the author](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/watir-general/s4krq9pa0B8)

Comment: Thanks buddy for your help...If I get the result back in hex format, it would have been more helpful..cheers for that mate..

Comment: `style("color")` is returning the colour as RGB values. So when comparing, you will need to convert the HEX to RGB. Several conversion options can be seen [here](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/76667)

Comment: Good find Justin, I was about to post the same link!

Comment: Thanks. And if you want to go the other way (RGB to HEX), here's a [starting point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/84421/converting-an-integer-to-a-hexadecimal-string-in-ruby)

Comment: Thank you guyz for very helpful and educative posts.

Comment: Glad to help -- @user1263912 if this post resolved your issue, please click the "Accept" button next to the answer so that others known it is complete.

Comment: @adamreed sorry for the delay. I can only able to "Accept" it from the same machine in my office. Thanks anyways Adam.

Comment: No worries man, glad it helped you out.  Thanks for coming back to mark it!