# Ruby: How to convert a list of integers into a hexadecimal string?

Tags: ruby

I have an array of integers that range from `0` to `255`, each representing two hexadecimal digits. I want to convert this array into one hexadecimal string using Ruby. How would I do that?

Comment: Does something like this help?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/84421/converting-an-integer-to-a-hexadecimal-string-in-ruby?rq=1

Comment: `arr.map { |n| n.to_s(16) }.join('')`

Comment: @Antonio I saw that, but it would convert characters like `1` to `1` instead of `01`, which is an issue because each element represents two hexadecimal characters.

Comment: `arr.map { |n| sprintf('%02x', n) }.join('')`

Comment: ...or a variant of @Dave's #2: `[0, 128, 255].each_with_object('') { |n,s| s << "%02x" % n } #=> "0080ff"` or `..(."%02x" % n).upcase..` if `=> "0080FF"` is desired.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With [`pack`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.2/Array.html#method-i-pack) and [`unpack`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.2/String.html#method-i-unpack): (or [`unpack1`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-unpack1) in Ruby 2.4+)

```
[0, 128, 255].pack('C*').unpack('H*')[0]
#=> "0080ff"

[0, 128, 255].pack('C*').unpack1('H*')
#=> "0080ff"
```

The actual binary hexadecimal string is already returned by `pack('C*')`:

```
[0, 128, 255].pack('C*')
#=> "\x00\x80\xFF"
```

`unpack('H*')` then converts it back to a human readable representation.

---

A light-weight alternative is [`sprintf`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.2/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf)-style formatting via  [`String@%`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.2/String.html#method-i-25) which takes an array:

```
'%02x%02x%02x' % [0, 128, 255]
#=> "0080ff"
```

`x` means hexadecimal number and `02` means 2 digits with leading zero.

Comment: This is roughly twice as fast as the other answer, if speed is important.

Comment: Ah, forgot about that; this will definitely be faster.

Answer (score 4):

I would do something like this:

```
array = [0, 128, 255]
array.map { |number| number.to_s(16).rjust(2, '0') }.join
#=> "0080ff"
```